# growisofs with file of specific extensions

Tags: command-line, dvd, iso, extension

Could any guru help me construct a command line that would let me add just (say) *.jpg files to a growisofs command.

It will need to recurse the folder structure and only add those .jpg files to the ISO image.

So something like the below recursing:

```
growisofs -Z /dev/dvdrw -R -J /some/files/*.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer, if ever, is in the man page of mkisofs, because growisofs forwards
the arguments about content to this program.

The newer releases of cdrtools support an option -find
with mkisofs. See
http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/man/cdrecord/mkisofs.8.html

After reading the description of -find, examples, and dead link, i would try

```
growisofs -Z /dev/dvdrw -R -J  -find /some/files -name '*.jpg'
```

In practice i don't try this, because i have my own program
xorriso for such jobs. :))

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/dvdrw -blank as_needed -joliet on \
        -findx /some/files -name '*.jpg' -exec add_missing / --
```

This will copy the *.jpg files underneath /some/files into
the ISO and create the directories which host them.
E.g. file /some/files/dogs/wuffy.jpg will become /dogs/wuffy.jpg in the ISO.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas